# How to change the values of an observables in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, observable

I have an observable like below,

```
       this.user$ = of(this.userService.getUserState());
```

I am binding usrFullNm of it in html,

```
      <p id="on-board" class="on-board-text" *ngIf="(user$|async) as 
  user">
   {{
  'OVERVIEW.WELCOME_SCREEN_ON_BOARD'
    | translate
      : {
          USER_NAME:
            user.usrFullNm
        }
}}</p>
```

mY    user.usrFullNm  is like

```
      Mike, Hasan         i.e == > [FN,LN]
```

Now I want to display only LN,for that I am not able to modify the observable,like

```
      this.user$.usrFullNm.split(',')[1]
```

Or do I need to change in the userService?

can any one suggest me help.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do as below

```js
this.user$ = of(this.userService.getUserState())
.pipe(map(user=>user.usrFullNm.split(',')[1]))
```

The **map** we are using is a Rxjs operator. you can learn all operators here (https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/).